# How to solve SchemaValidationFailedException: Child is not present in schema

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I'm trying to use Databroker of MD-SAL to save a list of data, after modifying the yang file and InstanceIdentifier many times but always facing similar validation issue, for example

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: TransactionCommitFailedException{message=canCommit encountered an unexpected failure, errorList=[RpcError [message=canCommit encountered an unexpected failure, severity=ERROR, errorType=APPLICATION, tag=operation-failed, applicationTag=null, info=null, cause=org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.data.impl.schema.tree.SchemaValidationFailedException: Child /(urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:testDataBroker?revision=2015-01-05)service-datas is not present in schema tree.]]}
        at org.opendaylight.yangtools.util.concurrent.MappingCheckedFuture.wrapInExecutionExc`

My goal is to use rpc save-device-info to get data from rest. Then use databroker api to save data in the memory and finally test if the data could be succesfully replicated into other cluster nodes.

Yang file:

```
module testDataBroker {
  yang-version 1;
  namespace "urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:testDataBroker";
  prefix "testDataBroker";

  revision "2015-01-05" {
    description "Initial revision of testDataBroker model";
  }

  container service-datas {
    list service-data {
        key "service-id";
        uses service-id;
        uses device-info;
      }
  }

  grouping device-info {
    container device-info {
        leaf device-name {
           type string;
           config false;
        }

        leaf device-description {
            type string;
            config false;
        }
      }
  }

  grouping service-id {
    leaf service-id {
        type string;
        mandatory true;
    }
  }

  rpc save-device-info {
    input {
        uses service-id;
        uses device-info;
    }
    output {
        uses device-info;
    }
   }

   rpc get-device-info {
      output {
        uses device-info;
      }
   }
  }
```

Java Code

```
    @Override public Future<RpcResult<SaveDeviceInfoOutput>> saveDeviceInfo(SaveDeviceInfoInput input) {
      String name = input.getDeviceInfo().getDeviceName();
      String description = input.getDeviceInfo().getDeviceDescription();
      String serviceId = input.getServiceId();

      WriteTransaction writeTransaction = dataBroker.newWriteOnlyTransaction();
      DeviceInfo deviceInfo = new DeviceInfoBuilder().setDeviceDescription(description).setDeviceName(name).build();
      ServiceData serviceData = new ServiceDataBuilder().setServiceId(serviceId).setDeviceInfo(deviceInfo).build();
      InstanceIdentifier<ServiceData> instanceIdentifier =
        InstanceIdentifier.builder(ServiceDatas.class).child(ServiceData.class, serviceData.getKey()).build();

      writeTransaction.put(LogicalDatastoreType.CONFIGURATION, instanceIdentifier, serviceData, true);

      boolean isFailed = false;
      try {
          writeTransaction.submit().get();
          log.info("Create containers succeeded!");

       } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
          log.error("Create containers failed: ", e);
          isFailed = true;
      }

      return isFailed ?
        RpcResultBuilder.success(new SaveDeviceInfoOutputBuilder())
            .withError(RpcError.ErrorType.RPC, "Create container failed").buildFuture() :
        RpcResultBuilder.success(new SaveDeviceInfoOutputBuilder().setDeviceInfo(input.getDeviceInfo()))
            .buildFuture();
}
```

Really need your help. Thanks.

Update:
With the same version of md-sal bundles, I installed feature odl-toaster on only one ODL instead of cluster nodes. It seems like rpc from odl-toaster is working properly on single node.

Comment: How do you register your RPC implementation? What does your blueprint xml file look like?

Comment: Thanks for the help. BindingAwareBroker.RpcRegistration<?>rpcProviderRegistry.addRpcImplementation(TestDataBrokerService.class) and     <reference id="dataBroker"
            interface="org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.binding.api.DataBroker"
               odl:type="default"/>

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that rpc is also clustered. Sometimes the rpc request hit on other nodes which didn't deploy the same bundles. Now the problem has been solved after the bundle is distrubted on each node.